# Multiple Call FB.init

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an project and in this project I have to use 2 differents Facebook's Applications.

For example: First application request scope: 'email,user_likes' and Second application request scope: 'manage_pages '

My question is: can I call FB.init() more than one time with differents appIds? I know I can do this, I want to know if this is an best practice.

Example:

```
function callAuth() {
  FB.init( {
    appId: '12345678',
    xfbml: true,
    status: 'v2.7'
  });
  FB.login(function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
},
function callMsg() {
  FB.init( {
    appId: '987654321',
    xfbml: true,
    status: 'v2.7'
  });
  FB.login(function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }, {scope: 'manage_pages'});
}
```

Can anyone, help me with this?

Comment: It is definitively not best practice, and I would not be surprised if this causes additional problems somewhere down the line. You should try to avoid using more than one app id on one page. If you really need your users to interact with both app ids, then do it on different pages.

Comment: Thanks! I try this, and for now this works. No problems with this. But you're right, maybe this causes additional problems somewhere. But I really need to do something like this, because I can't use one app for request differents scopes authorizations. Because, for example, in Application with scope Manage_Pages the number of request doesn't support others scopes. For this I create new Application.

Comment: "the number of request doesn't support others scopes" - what exactly do you mean with that? do you hit api limits? if yes, using several apps to circumvent limits is the wrong way.

Comment: nope! I mean: the propose of application is different. For a better organization, I want to have one application for only request scope: user_likes (for example) and have another application for only request scope: manage_pages. Why I need this? For example: if I have users of different countries and for each country I have differens appId, I will need to call FB.init with dynamic appID (depending on the country)

Comment: hi @DaniloVaz, did you manage to solve the problem? I have a different use-case: the app is supposed to add Page tabs. Facebook allows only 1 page tab per app, so I need to have 2 apps. I wonder if I can use Facebook JS SDK. Otherwise I will need to use redirects, probably.